# sonarqube reporting private static methods as unused for c#

Tags: c#, static, sonarqube, private

I am getting sonarqube issue as [image]

It is reporting all private static members as unused. Is it a false posetive from sonarqube or I am missing something here?

Comment: Are they being used..? Since they're private, they would have to be used within that class. If they're not being used within that class, they are of no use, and can be removed.

Comment: Seems like a false positive, since code lens shows that there are 6 references. Unless these references are from other private static methods that are not used anywhere

Comment: Can you add `GetParamValue` method body?

Comment: I got the same thing here.  I'm using SonarQube 6.0 and MSBuild SonarQube Runner 2.1